# Can't connect my AirPods via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

Hi so I've uninstalled all the drivers and reinstalled them. I've gone to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and changed settings around, still no change. Airpods are stuck on "not set up", can't connect them. Also tried to reset the AirPods, made sure they work on all my devices (they do). Only doesn't work on my laptop. Not sure what to really do :(

Comment: I finally got it to connect but now there is no option to select the airpods as an output device so there is no way to get audio.

Comment: This issue somehow resolved itself. Not sure how though.